# Reducing overlapping intervals in Pandas dataframe in an optimal fashion

Tags: python, performance, pandas, group-by, reduce

I am messing around with a data set in Pandas with two category columns, as well as a lower bound and an upper bound for every line. The combinations of values in the two category columns are not unique.

The lower and upper bounds form an interval, which may overlap for the same combination of category column values. I would like to reduce the overlapping intervals for a given combination of category values to non-overlapping intervals.

My own solution can be seen below, but I want to know if anyone know of better way to do it performance wise. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Define data
df = pd.DataFrame({'CatA':['A','B']*8,'CatB':['C','C','D','D']*4,
'Lower':[17,132,81,4,2,67,69,4,39,13,0,35,37,164,57,180],
'Upper':[85,190,161,38,191,69,183,62,70,30,89,155,134,168,110,187]})

#Identify overlapping intervals
tmp = df.sort_values(['CatA','CatB','Lower']).reset_index()
tmp.loc[0,'InPrev'] = False
tmp.loc[1:,'InPrev'] = tmp.loc[1:,'Lower']>tmp.loc[:14,'Upper']
tmp['GrpCount'] = tmp.groupby(['CatA','CatB'])['InPrev'].cumsum()

#Compute extremes of intervals
red_df = tmp.groupby(['CatA','CatB','GrpCount'])\
.agg({'Lower':np.min,'Upper':np.max})\
.reset_index()[['CatA','CatB','Lower','Upper']]
```

Comment: You know you don't have to hard-code this: `tmp.loc[1:,'Lower']>tmp.loc[:14,'Upper']`, right? You can use `shift()` instead.

Comment: @IanS: I was not aware of that one, no.... Thanks for adding it in :)

Comment: I'm afraid it won't do much to improve performance though. I couldn't think of a better way than yours...

Comment: That is fine.... Thank you very much for pitching in... The `shift() ` cleaned up two lines of the code, so that is already an improvement